# Java XPath "if" statement

Tags: java, xml, if-statement, xpath

I have some problems when I use `if` statement inside a `for` loop to delete some nodes in a XML document, because I don't understand why my counters become to 0 after put the `if` statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("input3.xml"));


    XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expres = xpath.compile("//TNMS/TPaths/TPath[Topology/LayerSet/NonTerminatedLayers/Layer='RS64']");
    NodeList PathsCount = (NodeList) expres.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    System.out.println("Inicia el Borrado:");

    for (int i = 0; i < PathsCount.getLength(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);

        XPathExpression exprueba = xpath.compile("/TNMS/TPaths/TPath[1]/Topology/LayerSet/TerminatedLayers");
        NodeList Count = (NodeList) exprueba.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Hay " + Count.getLength());
        int countvar = Count.getLength();

        XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//TNMS/TPaths/TPath[Topology/LayerSet/NonTerminatedLayers/Layer='RS64']");
        Node b13Node = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
        b13Node.getParentNode().removeChild(b13Node);
    }
```

I see next in the output:

```
Inicia el Borrado:
0

Hay 0

1

Hay 1

2

Hay 1

3

Hay 0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><TNMS>
    <TPaths>

    </TPaths>
</TNMS>BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

But when i agree the `if` statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("input3.xml"));


        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expres = xpath.compile("//TNMS/TPaths/TPath[Topology/LayerSet/NonTerminatedLayers/Layer='RS64']");
        NodeList PathsCount = (NodeList) expres.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println("Inicia el Borrado:");

        for (int i = 0; i < PathsCount.getLength(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);

            XPathExpression exprueba = xpath.compile("/TNMS/TPaths/TPath[1]/Topology/LayerSet/TerminatedLayers");
            NodeList Count = (NodeList) exprueba.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("Hay " + Count.getLength());
            int countvar = Count.getLength();

            if (countvar == 1) {
                XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("//TNMS/TPaths/TPath[Topology/LayerSet/NonTerminatedLayers/Layer='RS64']");
                Node b13Node = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
                b13Node.getParentNode().removeChild(b13Node);
            }
        }
```

the output is the next:

```
    Inicia el Borrado:
0

Hay 0

1

Hay 0

2

Hay 0

3

Hay 0
```

and the erase is failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected result? The code inside the `if` statement will only be executed when `countvar` is 1. But what is changing `countvar`? Does it ever change?

Comment: Please consider posting your XML source. If the problem is in your XPath expressions, there’s no way to test that without seeing your XML source.

Comment: Well thanks for your answers, I didn't post the XML because its so bog to share.. but it works doing some new methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be evaluating your xpath expressions inside your for loop relative to the nodes your iterating through. In your code you keep referencing `TPath[1]` which causes all kinds of weird problems.

Evaluate your xpath expressions relative to the current `TPaths` node which you stored in your `NodeList`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PathsCount.getLength(); i++)
{
    Node tPathsChild = PathsCount.item(i);
    System.out.println(i);

    // get the number of TerminatedLayers elements.
    XPathExpression exprueba = xpath.compile("Topology/LayerSet/TerminatedLayers");
    NodeList Count = (NodeList) exprueba.evaluate(tPathsChild, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("Hay " + Count.getLength());
    int countvar = Count.getLength();

    // remove this child if there are only 1 of them.
    if (countvar == 1) {
        tPathsChild.getParentNode().removeChild(tPathsChild);
    }
}
```

*FYI:* Java naming conventions are `camelCase`. It can be hard to read when they aren't in that format for a Java programmer.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, well Im new on Java and new in data programming, I was working about hardware so I excuse about that. but it works for me a will learn abut your explanation and the camelCase that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

you should debug it, but i think its because `Count.getLength()` returns 0 and your if statment will be executed only when it returns 1

thats probably because when you run program first time it deleted nodes and you didn't restored file when you tried it with if statment so your file is empty